# MiniDisplayPort to HDMI adapter not working

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, hdmi, dvi, video-adapter

OK, so I bought an MiniDisplayPort to HDMI adapter off [dx.com](http://dx.com/p/mini-displayport-male-to-hdmi-female-adapter-1080p-34025) and it doesn't work, before I angrily demand a refund I want to know whether there is anything I can do to get this to work.

I have a 2013 13inch MacBook Air

I have heard that I probably should have either got an [official apple (sponsored) one (for 40 dollars)](http://store.apple.com/au/product/HA824ZM/A/belkin-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter) or instead of Mini DisplayPort to HDMI get a Mini DisplayPort to DVI and then a DVI to HDMI adapter.

Comment: There are a number of MiniDP adapters that work out there, including Moshi (close to apple price) and Monoprice (low end) that I've had experience with, and I would trust the reviews of those in between (Kanex, I think). Do you mean it will output neither video nor audio? If it's just an audio issue, go to system preferences > Sound, and make sure **output** is set correctly. Some adapter/mac combos don't auto switch the audio-out on HDMI adapters.

Comment: have you tried switching hdmi cables?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the adapter?

I bought mine at [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2) for $6.82!

Notice it says with Audio support in the title.

> Mini DisplayPort to HDMI® Adapter w/ Audio Support Product Number:
>   5311

and it works purfectly on my MBA with the Sharp TV.

It is not worth for $4, but if you must, look in your about this mac, or your System Utility display if it shows the monitor/tv you just connected.

Comment: I will ask for a refund on my current cable and purchase this one, thanks for the cheap product recommendation.